# Selecting amongst equal sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $\pi:A\times B\to A$ be the projection satisfying $(a,b)\mapsto a$ for all $a\in A \text{ and } b\in B$.

The meaning is clear-- the image $A$ of function $\pi$ is the same $A$ that appears in the Cartesian product $A\times B$.

The situation seems less clear given, for example, a function $f:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $(x_1, x_2)\mapsto x_1+x_2$. Particularly, I interpret $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$ as the cartesian product of *two distinct copies* of the real numbers. If so, it seems a bit fishy to add an element of one copy of $\mathbb{R}$ to another copy of $\mathbb{R}$ since each copy of $\mathbb{R}$ comes with its own addition operation. (Of course, it is obvious in practice the natural way to do this, just add them as if everything was in the same copy of $\mathbb{R}$).

Is $x_1+x_2$ an element of the first copy of $\mathbb{R}$, the second copy, or a new copy?

I know that "don't worry about it" is, in practice, probably the appropriate answer. I am hoping for a more nuanced response.

Comment: The answer is whichever of the four might be most convenient in a given context - the first, the second, a third, or "don't worry about it." Usually it's the latter but sometimes the first three can be useful for visualizations.

Comment: One of the benefits of abstraction is that you can interpret the same thing in multiple ways. Similar to how a function can be a certain kind of relation defined as ordered pairs it can also be thought of as a mapping even though they are rather different at first glance. Which one you prefer typically depends on the problem you're examining.

Comment: "Particularly, I interpret R×R as the cartesian product of two distinct copies of the real numbers." This is subtle but that *isn't* how I interpret it.  I interpret $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$ as "the set of all ordered pairs $(a,b)$ where $a$ is a real number and $b$ is a real number".   Thus $\pi$ is the function "for any pair take the first element of the pair" and $f$ is the function "for any pair add the two elements of the pair together".  There's nothing wrong with those.

Comment: A little more:  I also interpret that there are not multiple copies of $\mathbb R$.  I see it that there is only one thing called "the real numbers" that exists and you can't copy it.  It's like a public library: everyone can look at it all at the same time but there's only one master instance of it.

Comment: @CyclotonicField I view abstraction slightly differently. A function, defined as ordered pairs, abstracts a specific kind of relationship amongst two sets. A function, defined as a map between spaces, abstracts this same idea in a slightly (usually insignificantly) different way; namely, the codomain is explicitly specified. The second definition is in fact an abstraction of the ordered pair definition if we equate the range with the codomain and use the ordered pairs to define a mapping rule.

Comment: @fleablood Your explanation makes sense. Do you know if yours is the standard interpretation? I recall a textbook (cannot recall the name offhand) describing $\mathbb{R}^n$ by referencing $n$ copies of $\mathbb{R}$ but I may have read to much into it.

Comment: fleablood's "interpretation" is the standard $ definition$.

Comment: " Do you know if yours is the standard interpretation? "  I'd be very loathe to say there is a standard interpretation much less that mine is it.  I think I'm with CyclotomicField on this in that abstractions are flexible.  Also there is a concept that as mathematics *is* pure abstraction if two mathematical constructs are equivilent they may be considered the same.  In this way copies, borrowing impressions from a master copy, popping a clone every time you hiccup are more or less the same thing.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet  I confess, I have a bit of a difficulty seeing Mithrandir's "interpretation".  I can see three copies of $\mathbb R$ lying around (sure, why not?) but I'm not really sure I see why adding a number from one copy to a number from another copy getting a number in the third copy needs to be so ... complicated... I suppose an analogy is if you buy an egg from Whole Foods, and some milk from Sprouts and mix them together to get a batter in Your Kitchen, it seems an unnecessary but not insurmountable confusion to specify *where* the ingredients are from.

Comment: @fleablood . The proposer's thinking is unclear because he does not employ a definition of a Cartesian product.  "If you discourse with me, you must define your terms." (Voltaire).

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Perhaps but that's a wee bit harsher that it need be. This could be a difference between individuals comfort of abstraction.  Consider the concept from my elementary school days of "the number line", and now consider the sentence "I bought 2 quarts of milk" is the number 2 in that sentence the same as the point labelled 2 on the number line. Now you and I would probably say "of course, the number line is an representation of numbers and the quarts of milk is a manifestation of a number". But a more literal or physical oriented student would find that perplexing... to be cont..

Comment: .. actually come to think of it the very first time I came across the cartesian product and ordered pairs it was *distinctly* as a physical point on a 2-D cartesian plane.  the x axis was *one* copy of $\mathbb R$ (as a number line) and the y axis was *another*.  They couldn't be the same thing because one was vertical and the other horizontal. But I had no issue that the indicated *numbers* which are *quantity* and I never had issue that the OP has that if you take a 2.7 value from one of the axis and add it to the 5.4 value from the other axis that what I was dealing with *were* numbers.